# How do I validate and "read-only" the file using CodeIgniter's File Uploading Class?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to upload an Excel file using CodeIgniter. What I want to do is to just read the file without moving/uploading it in my upload path which is required in the configuration.

Yup, I can use the native PHP's `$_FILES` superglobal variable. But, I like to use the library because it gives me extra security to my app.

So.. how can I upload a file using CI's File Uploading class without being uploaded to my server?

```
$config['upload_path'] = './public/uploads/';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|xls';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);

if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))
{
    $this->output->set_output(array('result' => FALSE, 'message' => $this->upload->display_errors()))->_display();
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    $data = $this->upload->data();

    // Let the model do his work!
    $this->load->model('Userlist_Model');
    $result = $this->Userlist_Model->extract_list($data);

    $this->output->set_output($result)->_display();
}
```

Comment: It's called an upload library for a reason. If you really want to read the content of the file then just use `$_FILES` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925236/how-to-read-content-of-csv-file-in-codeigniter

Comment: Oh! Got the idea. I'll just extend the library, grab the validation process from the `do_upload` method and then read the file using `$_FILES`. Thanks for the idea. +1

Comment: Once a file is posted it *is* on your server... somewhere - usually the tmp files directory (which if you are on shared hosting is usually only used internally and not accessible). I don't understand why you went through the trouble of extending the core when you could have just as easily stored the file in a "permanent" temporary location and deleted the file after processing. Seems more elegant to me. In any case, I'm pretty sure that this "added" functionality in your answer will actually be pervasive through any use of the upload library. So you might see images failing to upload elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my solution: Just extend the Upload.php (CI_Upload) by creating `MY_Upload` inside the libraries folder. Copying the `do_upload()` method then remove the part where the upload starts:

**MY_Upload.php**

```
class MY_Upload extends CI_Upload
{
    public function validate_file($field = 'userfile')
    {
        // Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
        if (isset($_FILES[$field]))
        {
            $_file = $_FILES[$field];
        }
        // Does the field name contain array notation?
        elseif (($c = preg_match_all('/(?:^[^\[]+)|\[[^]]*\]/', $field, $matches)) > 1)
        {
            $_file = $_FILES;
            for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++)
            {
                // We can't track numeric iterations, only full field names are accepted
                if (($field = trim($matches[0][$i], '[]')) === '' OR ! isset($_file[$field]))
                {
                    $_file = NULL;
                    break;
                }

                $_file = $_file[$field];
            }
        }

        if ( ! isset($_file))
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected', 'debug');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Is the upload path valid?
        if ( ! $this->validate_upload_path())
        {
            // errors will already be set by validate_upload_path() so just return FALSE
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Was the file able to be uploaded? If not, determine the reason why.
        if ( ! is_uploaded_file($_file['tmp_name']))
        {
            $error = isset($_file['error']) ? $_file['error'] : 4;

            switch ($error)
            {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
                    $this->set_error('upload_file_exceeds_limit', 'info');
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
                    $this->set_error('upload_file_exceeds_form_limit', 'info');
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL:
                    $this->set_error('upload_file_partial', 'debug');
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE:
                    $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected', 'debug');
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
                    $this->set_error('upload_no_temp_directory', 'error');
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
                    $this->set_error('upload_unable_to_write_file', 'error');
                    break;
                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION:
                    $this->set_error('upload_stopped_by_extension', 'debug');
                    break;
                default:
                    $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected', 'debug');
                    break;
            }

            return FALSE;
        }

        // Set the uploaded data as class variables
        $this->file_temp = $_file['tmp_name'];
        $this->file_size = $_file['size'];

        // Skip MIME type detection?
        if ($this->detect_mime !== FALSE)
        {
            $this->_file_mime_type($_file);
        }

        $this->file_type = preg_replace('/^(.+?);.*$/', '\\1', $this->file_type);
        $this->file_type = strtolower(trim(stripslashes($this->file_type), '"'));
        $this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($_file['name']);
        $this->file_ext  = $this->get_extension($this->file_name);
        $this->client_name = $this->file_name;

        // Is the file type allowed to be uploaded?
        if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filetype())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype', 'debug');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // if we're overriding, let's now make sure the new name and type is allowed
        if ($this->_file_name_override !== '')
        {
            $this->file_name = $this->_prep_filename($this->_file_name_override);

            // If no extension was provided in the file_name config item, use the uploaded one
            if (strpos($this->_file_name_override, '.') === FALSE)
            {
                $this->file_name .= $this->file_ext;
            }
            else
            {
                // An extension was provided, let's have it!
                $this->file_ext = $this->get_extension($this->_file_name_override);
            }

            if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filetype(TRUE))
            {
                $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filetype', 'debug');
                return FALSE;
            }
        }

        // Convert the file size to kilobytes
        if ($this->file_size > 0)
        {
            $this->file_size = round($this->file_size/1024, 2);
        }

        // Is the file size within the allowed maximum?
        if ( ! $this->is_allowed_filesize())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_filesize', 'info');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Are the image dimensions within the allowed size?
        // Note: This can fail if the server has an open_basedir restriction.
        if ( ! $this->is_allowed_dimensions())
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_invalid_dimensions', 'info');
            return FALSE;
        }

        // Sanitize the file name for security
        $this->file_name = $this->_CI->security->sanitize_filename($this->file_name);

        // Truncate the file name if it's too long
        if ($this->max_filename > 0)
        {
            $this->file_name = $this->limit_filename_length($this->file_name, $this->max_filename);
        }

        // Remove white spaces in the name
        if ($this->remove_spaces === TRUE)
        {
            $this->file_name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $this->file_name);
        }

        if ($this->file_ext_tolower && ($ext_length = strlen($this->file_ext)))
        {
            // file_ext was previously lower-cased by a get_extension() call
            $this->file_name = substr($this->file_name, 0, -$ext_length).$this->file_ext;
        }

        /*
         * Validate the file name
         * This function appends an number onto the end of
         * the file if one with the same name already exists.
         * If it returns false there was a problem.
         */
        $this->orig_name = $this->file_name;
        if (FALSE === ($this->file_name = $this->set_filename($this->upload_path, $this->file_name)))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        /*
         * Run the file through the XSS hacking filter
         * This helps prevent malicious code from being
         * embedded within a file. Scripts can easily
         * be disguised as images or other file types.
         */
        if ($this->xss_clean && $this->do_xss_clean() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->set_error('upload_unable_to_write_file', 'error');
            return FALSE;
        }

        /*
         * Set the finalized image dimensions
         * This sets the image width/height (assuming the
         * file was an image). We use this information
         * in the "data" function.
         */
        $this->set_image_properties($this->upload_path.$this->file_name);

        // Return true if the file passed the validation
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```